# Qual a diferença entre 'CSS Filter Effects' e 'CSS filter() function'?

Tags: html, css, svg

Estou pesquisando sobre o suporte dos navegadores quanto a propriedade `filter` do **CSS** e a tag `<filter>` do **SVG**.

Meu link de busca: https://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Qual a diferença entre ***CSS Filter Effects*** e ***CSS filter() function***?
No navegador *Chrome for Android* um é compatível o outro não com a versão 74.

Acredito que possa ser algo haver com isso:

```
// HTML
<filter id="idqualquer">
    // Efeito a ser aplicado
</filter>

// CSS
filter: url(#idqualquer); // Este provavelmente não deve funcionar
filter: gray;
```

Mas ainda sim não possuo certeza.

Comment: Acredito que o `filter` function seja para as manipulações com **SVG**, me corrijam se eu estiver errada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Filter Effects:** Os Filter Effects são uma forma de processar a renderização de um elemento antes de ser exibido no documento. Normalmente, renderizar um elemento via CSS ou SVG pode ser descrito como se o elemento, incluindo seus filhos, fosse desenhado em um buffer (como uma imagem rasterizada) e então esse buffer fosse composto no pai dos elementos. Os filtros aplicam um efeito antes do estágio de composição. Exemplos de tais efeitos são o desfoque, alteração da intensidade da cor e distorção de imagem.

Segue um exemplo de código utilizando o Filter Effects: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_fegaussianblur

**filter() function:** Os filtros CSS são uma ferramenta poderosa que os desenvolvedores podem usar para obter efeitos visuais variados (como os filtros do Photoshop para o navegador). A propriedade de filtro CSS fornece acesso a efeitos como desfoque ou mudança de cor na renderização de um elemento antes de o elemento ser exibido. Os filtros são comumente usados para ajustar a renderização de uma imagem, um plano de fundo ou uma borda.

Filtros possíveis:

- blur()
- brightness()
- contrast()
- drop-shadow(
- grayscale()
- hue-rotate()
- invert()
- opacity()
- saturate()
- sepia()
- url() - for applying SVG

Segue um exemplo de código utilizando a propriedade filter: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_filter_grayscale

Observações: Segundo o site Can I Use (https://caniuse.com/#search=filter), o filter não tem suporte para todos os navegadores, e por esse motivo, é interessante utilizar o Autoprefixer CSS online (https://autoprefixer.github.io/) para adicionar os vendors prefixes (-webkit-filter) e ter o suporte necessário para rodar nos navegadores.

---

Links de busca:

https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/

https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterCSSImageValue

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/